# conflict and otherness between data produced by a single clr stored procedure in two server

Tags: sql-server, clr

I have a very special problem !
I have a clr stored procedure that is called by a windows application . there is not any problem when i do it in local instance of sqlserver . the problem occurs when using a remote server for doing this job . in this situation clr can't do it good . my output data is wrong and there are many differences in two servers' data . i want to know why these conflicts happen by a single clr sp ? 
more info : i have a "transactionscope" in clr . 
thanks for your help !

Comment: The first step in debugging this would be to make a copy of your production data on your local install (or create a development database on another remote server), and see whether your incorrect output data is still incorrect.

Comment: Do you really expect people to be able to give decent answers, given the information you've presented? You say there are output differences, but give no *examples*. More importantly, we can't see *any* of the code. Since a CLR stored procedure can perform virtually *any* task, you expect us to deduce the structure of the procedure and where the problem lies by telling us it uses `transactionscope`?